# An object reference is required for the non-static field,method, or property dataGridView1

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two forms in my Windows Forms application. I want to take some parameters from the second form to filter the `DataGridView` in my first form.

Here is my `FilterGrid` method on the first form:

```
public void FilterGrid(string query)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Tamer Memili\Desktop\Urun.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
    connection.Open();

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = query;

    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
    connection.Close();
}
```

I have to define this method as public static void to access it from form2, but when I do that, I get an error on this line:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property dataGridView1

How can I do that?

Comment: Static methods can't access instance members, remove the static modifier and add a reference of form1 to form2 so you can call the method without the static modifier

Comment: how can i add a reference to form 1 and form2? can you write it as a code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make the FilterGrid method as non static :

```
public void FilterGrid(string query)
```

Then send  the form1 reference to form2.
  I suspect at some  point you do soemthing like this

```
   Form2 form2 = new Form2()
    form2.showDialog()
```

You can  add a new constructor into Form2 which would look something like this

```
 Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
   {
     this._form1Instance =form1Instance
   }
```

and pass  the instance of Form1 to Form2 when you construct it:

```
  Form2 form2 = new Form2(this)
  form2.showDialog()
```

Then, when you want to call the filter form FilterGrid from form 2 all you do is

```
  _form1Instance.FilterGrid("my query")
```

I hope this helps