# Filter DataGridView in Form1 from Form2

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I created a filter in Form2(SearchWindow), that filters the values in a DataGridView found in Form1(frPlanMain).

The problem is that i get the following **error** :

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` .

Problem is that I am not really sure how to make use of DataGridView(dGVPlan) in Form2.

Am I missing a string or something ?

Code for **Form1** is:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frPlanMain

    Public Sub goButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles goButton.Click

        Dim MyPath As String = "D:\" + goTextBox.Text

        Dim cb As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
            {
                .DataSource = MyPath,
                .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
            }
        cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0; IMEX=1; HDR=NO;")
        Dim cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection With
            {
                .ConnectionString = cb.ConnectionString
            }
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
            <Statement>
                    SELECT 
                        F1 As NrFir, 
                        F2 As TechSudura, 
                        F3 As TechLP, 
                        F4 As HNr, 
                        F6 As Sectiune,
                        F7 As Culoare1,
                        F8 As Culoare2,
                        F9 As Lungime,
                        F11 As PozitieStanga,
                        F14 As PozitieDreata,
                        F17 As MSpec,
                        F19 As TerminalSt,
                        F20 As GumitaSt,
                        F21 As TerminalDr,
                        F22 As GumitaDr
                    FROM 
                        [WI$]
                </Statement>.Value, cn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        cn.Close()
        dGVPlan.DataSource = dt

        SearchWindow.Show()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Code for **Form2** is:

```
Public Class SearchWindow
    Private Sub SearchGoButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchGoButton.Click

        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To frPlanMain.dGVPlan.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To frPlanMain.dGVPlan.ColumnCount - 1
                If frPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = SearchTextBox.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Item found")
                    temp = 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If temp = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Item not found")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: In which line the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" message occurs? Which form? frPlanMain or SearchWindow?

Comment: It shows in SearchWindow.

Comment: [Pass a reference of `Form1` to `Form2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23970791/3773066) then refactor the desired filtering code in `Form1` into a method to be called in `Form2`.

Answer (score 0):

In SearchWindow

```
     Public Property dGVPlan() As DataGridView
           Get
             Return _dGVPlan
           End Get
           Set
            _dGVPlan = Value
           End Set
     End Property
     Private _dGVPlan As DataGridView
```

In frPlanMain

```
     cn.Close()
     dGVPlan.DataSource = dt
     Dim f As New SearchWindow()
     f.dGVPlan = frPlanMain.dGVPlan
     SearchWindow.Show()
```

use that grid variable _dGVPlan in SearchWindow

```
     If _dGVPlan.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = SearchTextBox.Text Then
                MsgBox("Item found")
                temp = 1
            End If
```

Comment: I get the error :  Dgv is not a member of frPlanMain. At      f.dGVPlan = frPlanMain.Dgv

Comment: Didnt check that code works or not, as am not VB dev. Edited anyhow. :)